# Getting error on function call

Tags: c++

```
void main()
{
    int a2[] =  {1};
    int a3[] = {1, 2};
    int a4[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int a5[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int a6[] = {3, 3, 4, 4};
    int a7[] = {3, 2, 3, 4};
    int a8[] = {4, 1, 2, 3};
    int a9[] = {1, 1};
    araay (a6,3);
}

void araay(int arg[], int length)
{
    int sumEven = 0;
    int sumOdd = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<=length; i++)
    {
      if (arg[i]%2 == 0)
        sumEven += arg[i];
      else
        sumOdd += arg[i];
    }

    cout << sumOdd - sumEven;

}
```

This my code for that takes an array of integers as an argument and returns a value based on the sums of the even and odd numbers in the array but the error i am getting is

`araay identifier is not found`

Comment: Declare the function before you call it. And `main` should return `int`.

Comment: Although it may not be easy to search for, there are other questions here just like this.

Comment: Your condition in 'for' loop is wrong. Let it be a work for you to figure where is the error.

Comment: @enedil -- I think the condition is correct, it's just not an idiomatic use of the term `length`. Note the call `araay(a6,3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put

```
void araay(int arg[], int length);
```

before `main() { ...` to declare your function.

Comment: Can we name all the above arrays the same name , like `a1` for all arrays ?

Comment: _'Can we name all the above arrays the same name'_ No.

Comment: Not in the same scope. How would you expect the compiler to figure out which one you want if they all had the same name?

Comment: through arguments ? isn't ?

Comment: @RabiiKhalid What do you mean? You can call you function with any of these arrays e.g. `araay (a8,sizeof(a8));`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have only definition of your function `araay(...)`. You need to add declaration of this function before `main()` to provide information about function `aray(...)` for `main()`.

You always must put at least declaration of function before `main()` to be able use it in `main()`. Declaration of function before `main()` can be combine with its definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your function above main before you call it. Or you can put the whole function above the main and its working fine.

```
void araay(int arg[], int length)
{
    int sumEven = 0;
    int sumOdd = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<=length; i++)
    {
      if (arg[i]%2 == 0)
        sumEven += arg[i];
      else
        sumOdd += arg[i];
    }

    cout << sumOdd - sumEven;

}

int main()
{
....
}
```